# Is there any error with my code? I am trying to create an extension to autofill fields with specific details on a single web page for firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to create a autofill extension for firefox to automatically fill the fields in a specific webpage with predefined values. I am new to this and have used several online sources for help. I am getting no error but when I click on the button it doesn't fill the data. I have tried all the methods but I am not sure where the mistake is.

This is the code I have used

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "AutoFills Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "https://comm.proxy.com/send/bulk-app/*",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "https://comm.proxy.com/send/bulk-app/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://comm.proxy.com/send/bulk-app/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"] 
      }
    ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  
  const predefinedData = {
    "TemplateName": "FLEX/NEWSFEED",
    "dropdownValue": "CRITICAL" 
  };
  
   
    function autofillForm() {
      const form = document.querySelector("form-control"); // Replace with your specific form selector
      if (form) {
        // Autofill text fields
        form.querySelector("input[name='templateName']").value = predefinedData.TemplateName;
        const dropdown = form.querySelector("select[name='Priority']");
        if (dropdown) {
          for (let option of dropdown.options) {
            if (option.text === predefinedData.dropdownValue) {
              option.selected = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          
        }
      }
    }
  
    autofillForm();
  });
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AutoFill Extension</title>
  <style>
    button {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #0074b3;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>AutoFill Extension</h2>
  <p>Click the button below to autofill the form:</p>
  <button id="autofillButton">Autofill Form</button>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const autofillButton = document.getElementById("autofillButton");
  
    autofillButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      // Send a message to your content script to initiate autofill
      browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { command: "autofill" });
      });
    });
  });

I am also adding the name, id and class of the html page I am working with
id="templateName"
class="form-control"
name="templateName"
type="text"
data-reactid=".0.2.3.1.0"
```

Any help is highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to solve this issue, but I thought I'd suggest to you to possibly use the input.placeholder attribute instead of trying to autofill fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of “*DOMContentLoaded*” with “*load*” because the former is very premature and not suitable for your needs. So your listeners would now look like this…

```
document.addEventListener('load',function(){
// whatever is in here
}
```

**NB:** DOMContentLoaded is useful for making JS performance measurements etc and fires before stylesheets, images, subframes, and I don’t know what else have loaded.

Btw, I’ve also worked on auto-filling form fields on pages… and not only did I use the very last *load* event trigger but I also wait for an additional 3-5 seconds (delay) for everything to load perfectly before filling out form fields!

Some pages are big and complex so you need to give them plenty of time to settle down before operating.

Comment: Hi,
I have tried your suggestion and was not able to make it work. Are there any other ways you think I can change to make the thing work?